# C# List<T> definition in gRPC proto3

Tags: c#, grpc

Like title says, whats is definition of List is for gRPC proto3, tried to search in https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3 and found "repeated" type, but seems its read only, map is not solution, since I dont use index keys. What I need gRPC solution for List Thanks.

Comment: Why would you want it to not be readonly anyway?

Comment: because I cant var currentlist = new Google.Protobuf.Collections.RepeatedField<myClass>(); throws "property or indexer myclass cannot be assigned to -- it is read only

Comment: That line of code *wouldn't* fail - but I suspect what you're actually doing is `myProto.SomeRepeatedField = new RepeatedField<OtherClass>()` which would give the error you're talking about.

Comment: I found out why, its ALREADY defines new List<T> in proto and adding new item in list works fine.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Although the property for the repeated field in the generated code is read-only, it's still mutable. Just add to the existing `RepeatedField<T>` rather than assigning a new value. Note that `RepeatedField<T>.Add` is overloaded so you can add a whole sequence in one call, even in a collection initializer, e.g.

```
string[] allNames = ...;
var message = new MyMessage
{
    Names = { allNames.Where(n => n.Length > 5) }
};
```

Comment: Post above there is why it throws error about readonly because ITS ALREADY has new List<T>, no need to assign again, anyways thanks for help.

Comment: @Joel2: I don't understand what you mean by "Post above there" - and note that there's no `List<T>` involved at all. `RepeatedField<T>` is a different type.

Comment: Sorry maybe I was rushed to say, but yes Repeatedfield<T> is somehow already assigned while app is running, which I weird, since it should throw errors about null objects but seems it ok

Comment: @Joel2: What do you mean by "somehow already assigned"? It's a read-only property which is initialized during object creation - there's nothing particularly unusual about that.